# Copy end of string and paste to new column

Tags: awk, sed, paste, cut

Which UNIX command do I use to copy the end of a string in column 1 and paste it to a new column?

For example,

```
> $ head -3 test1.bed 
> HLA:HLA00001_A_01:01:01:01_3503  1 
> HLA:HLA02169_A_01:01:01:02N_3291 1 
> HLA:HLA14798_A_01:01:01:03_2903  1
```

Becomes,

```
> $ head -3 test1.bed 
> HLA:HLA00001_A_01:01:01:01_3503  1 3503
> HLA:HLA02169_A_01:01:01:02N_3291 1 3291
> HLA:HLA14798_A_01:01:01:03_2903  1 2903
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{n=split($1,a,"_"); print $0, a[n]}' file

HLA:HLA00001_A_01:01:01:01_3503  1  3503
HLA:HLA02169_A_01:01:01:02N_3291 1  3291
HLA:HLA14798_A_01:01:01:03_2903  1 2903
```