# awk copy info after space to new column

Tags: awk

I have data with an hour value and would like to copy just the hourly value from the date column to a new column.
Given:

```
01/02/2021 07:00,54596894,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 09:00,55038801,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 06:00,55038845,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 02:00,78434342,0.004,SIEA
01/02/2021 15:00,78434429,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 17:00,78434838,0.005,SIEA
01/02/2021 05:00,78508079,2.715,SIEA
01/02/2021 19:00,79083881,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 12:00,82928135,0,SIEA
01/02/2021 01:00,83889954,0,SIEA
```

I would like the result to be:

```
01/02/2021 07:00,54596894,0,SIEA,07
01/02/2021 09:00,55038801,0,SIEA,09
01/02/2021 06:00,55038845,0,SIEA,06
01/02/2021 02:00,78434342,0.004,SIEA,02
01/02/2021 15:00,78434429,0,SIEA,15
01/02/2021 17:00,78434838,0.005,SIEA,17
01/02/2021 05:00,78508079,2.715,SIEA,05
01/02/2021 19:00,79083881,0,SIEA,19
01/02/2021 12:00,82928135,0,SIEA,12
01/02/2021 01:00,83889954,0,SIEA,01
```

I've been working with awk but have only been able to get it to give me the first part of the column.  I need to get what's after the space and only two characters after the space.
[Copy end of string and paste to new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123181/copy-end-of-string-and-paste-to-new-column)

awk '{n=split($1,a," "); print $0","a[n]}'

produces

```
01/02/2021 07:00,54596894,0,SIEA,01/02/2021
01/02/2021 09:00,55038801,0,SIEA,01/02/2021
...
```

I'm ok if I get all the characters after the space (though I'd prefer only to get the two immediate characters) but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to select the other side of the split.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for `split`. Set the field separator as `:` or   (space) and the output field separator as `,`. Then print the whole record and the 2nd field.

```
awk -F '[: ]' -v OFS=, '{print $0,$2}'
```

Comment: Hate to ask more, but for my own knowledge, can you clarify the '[: ]'  I understand that it is the field separator designation because of the -F but are the brackets and semicolon the necessary components to use space as the separator?

Comment: square bracket denote charsets, so the field delimiter is either space or colon.  There are special chars in a charset as well, for example `-` can mean range. A working knowledge of regex will go a long way.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F, '{split($1,a,"[ :]"); print $0 FS a[2]}' file

01/02/2021 07:00,54596894,0,SIEA,07
01/02/2021 09:00,55038801,0,SIEA,09
01/02/2021 06:00,55038845,0,SIEA,06
01/02/2021 02:00,78434342,0.004,SIEA,02
01/02/2021 15:00,78434429,0,SIEA,15
01/02/2021 17:00,78434838,0.005,SIEA,17
01/02/2021 05:00,78508079,2.715,SIEA,05
01/02/2021 19:00,79083881,0,SIEA,19
01/02/2021 12:00,82928135,0,SIEA,12
01/02/2021 01:00,83889954,0,SIEA,01
```

split based on two delimiters, the middle value is the hour digits.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{print $0","substr($2,1,2)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Explanation of code will be: Simply printing current line then printing a comma along with sub string of 2nd field of 2 characters(1st and 2nd characters).

Answer (score 3):

All `awk` solution are pretty good. Here is a simple `sed` that also does the job:

```sh
sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]{2}):.*/&,\1/' file

01/02/2021 07:00,54596894,0,SIEA,07
01/02/2021 09:00,55038801,0,SIEA,09
01/02/2021 06:00,55038845,0,SIEA,06
01/02/2021 02:00,78434342,0.004,SIEA,02
01/02/2021 15:00,78434429,0,SIEA,15
01/02/2021 17:00,78434838,0.005,SIEA,17
01/02/2021 05:00,78508079,2.715,SIEA,05
01/02/2021 19:00,79083881,0,SIEA,19
01/02/2021 12:00,82928135,0,SIEA,12
01/02/2021 01:00,83889954,0,SIEA,01
```

Comment: I was thinking of using sed, but i tend to find awk more intuitive (for me anyway). thanks though for the functional alternate

Answer (score 1):

Sed alternative:

```
sed -E 's/(^.*[[:space:]])([[:digit:]]{2})(:.*$)/\1\2\3,\2/' file
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -r -E, split the lines into 3 section specified between parenthesis and then print the first, second and third sections, followed by a comma and the third section again.

Answer (score 1):

here is another (more expensive) solution

```
$ paste -d, file <(cut -d: -f1 file | cut -d' ' -f2)
```